How to iterate over all folders and their subfolders and have AWK process each TXT file in the subfolders?
I want to iterate over all folders and their subfolders and print the names of the .TXT files (in the subfolders) whose first line contains the string CYCLE DATE (there may be spaces and/or underscores between CYCLE and DATE). Here's my attempt at solving this:
In files_and_folders.sh I entered this:
#!/bin/bash
find . -name '*.TXT' -exec awk 'NR == 1 && $0 ~ /CYCLE[_ ]+DATE/ { print FILENAME }'

At the bash command line I entered this:
bash files_and_folders.sh

That produced the following error message:
find: missing argument to -exec

What is the correct way to do this?

I'd split this problem like this:

Go over all files
for each file:

get the first line only
check for CYCLE DATE
print file name if found.



So,
#!/bin/bash
# Don't error on no file name matches:
shopt -s nullglob
# Enable recursive ** glob:
shopt -s globstar

for file in **/*.TXT ; do
  # first line only   # look for regex              # print file name
  #                   #  -q:   silently             #
  # -n 1: one line    #  -E: extended regexes       #
  head -n 1 "${file}" | grep -q -E 'CYCLE[_ ]+DATE' && echo "${file}"
  # or your elegant:
  # awk 'NR == 1 && $0 ~ /CYCLE[_ ]+DATE/ { print FILENAME }' "${file}"
done

Of course, instead of grep you can use awk to analyze your line, but frankly, that's unnecessarily complex here. Your regular expression is very simple (CYCLE, then "space" (at least once), then DATE), so a simple regex engine like grep can do the job.

The problem with your find is that you use neither ';' nor '{}' after -exec, so find can't understand where the command it should execute is done (or where it should put the file it found when doing the invocation).
But since this doesn't even need find and can be done completely without, I'd personally say for file in GLOB; do … done is easier to remember than find -name 'PATTERN' -exec Some complicated syntax '{}' ';'.

Observe that if you are able to subvert bash into understanding **/*.TXT as all *.TXT at all levels then you might call GNU AWK once following way awk 'FNR==1&&/pattern/{print FILENAME}' **/*.TXT note you need to use FNR (file number row) in that case.

@Daweo true! Would you care to post this as your own answer? Because then I could upvote it, and it would get the attention it deserves.

I did added second answer, which is composite of your and my original approach

Try this:
find . -name '*.TXT' -exec \
    awk 'FNR == 1 { if ( /CYCLE[_ ]+DATE/ ) print FILENAME; nextfile }' \
{} +

The {} + is to tell find to pass awk multiple files at a time instead of having to spawn a new subshell per file to call awk one file at a time. See the find man page.


What is the correct way to do this?

From find man page

-exec command ;
Execute command; true if 0 status is returned. All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an
argument consisting of ';' is encountered. The string '{}' is replaced
by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the
arguments to the command(...)

Observe trailing semicolon and that you should put {} to denote where to put filename, therefore to unveil paths to *.TXT files where 1st line matches some pattern one might do
find . -name '*.TXT' -exec awk 'NR==1&&/pattern/{print FILENAME}' {} \;

Observe that if you have big files you might speed-up that command by instructing GNU AWK to stop processing lines after 1st that is
find . -name '*.TXT' -exec awk 'NR==1&&/pattern/{print FILENAME}NR>1{exit}' {} \;


Alternative approach which is composite of Marcus Müller answer and my earlier answer
shopt -s globstar && awk 'FNR==1&&/pattern/{print FILENAME}' **/*.TXT

It does subvert bash into understanding **/*.TXT as any *.TXT file at any level and does call GNU AWK once. Keep in mind in this case FNR should be used rather than NR. In case files are huge following lines might be skipped following way
shopt -s globstar && awk 'FNR==1&&/pattern/{print FILENAME}FNR>1{nextfile}' **/*.txt

